# Bluetooth Pairing - HFP profile and Classic Bluetooth/BLE

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

Can any one help me on bluetooth pairing and communicating

1.Is it possible to view all the device trying to connect via Bluetooth in the application, **not by going to settings page.**

2 **Can we access data from devices that use standard profile like HFP,A2DP etc without MFi.(Classic bluetooth, not BLE) How is it done and which framework?**

Pls help and thanks in advance

3.(Edited) Is it possible to view all devices that uses BLE (standard profiles only HFP, A2DP )in the application by using Corebluetooth???

Comment: If understood your question correctly, HFP and A2DP are on a classic bluetooth, low energy cannot detect classic bluetooth profiles.

Comment: Then how is iphone paired with the accessories of samsung and all.. I want to take an input from bluetooth mic which is using classic bluetooth to my application. Is this possible.

Answer (score 6):

1. There are three types of devices you might want to connect via Bluetooth, being A) Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices B) Classic Bluetooth accessories participating in MFi program C) some generic Classic Bluetooth devices, like hands-free headsets.

With BLE devices you can do almost whatever you want. You can get a list of them inside your app, present it nicely and let the user choose a device to connect (or connect transparently).

MFi devices you can either see in Settings.app or in Accessory Picker popup (see [ExternalAccessory.framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html) for more details). However, you don't have control over the Accessory Picker. But after the user has selected the device there, you can see it programmatically as connected.

With standard Classic Bluetooth devices, like hands-frees, your one and only pairing option is to go to the Settings.app and pair from there. End of story.

So no, there's no such magic place where you can see all the devices around you. You should know in advance with which type of devices you need to communicate and react accordingly.

2. There's no standard framework to deal with standard Classic BT devices, different Apple frameworks are responsible for them. And in general, you can't do much, most communication is being done internally by the system. E.g. for hands-free devices you can only detect that such device was connected/disconnected (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776340/ios-how-to-discover-bluetooth-headset-and-its-events?lq=1)).
3. HFP and A2DP are Classic Bluetooth profiles that have nothing to do with BLE. You can't see a list of such devices around using CoreBluetooth.framework.