# iOS Bluetooth Device List

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, nsnotificationcenter

I would like to use Bluetooth as a drive for an app.

I need to be able to let the user pick a chosen device from 'Settings>Bluetooth>My Devices', so I am looking for how I can get this list in my code.

Once I have the details of the selected device, I would like to be able to register for notifications whenever this device is connected (or whenever any bluetooth device connects and I can parse the data to check for a match).

The devices I am looking for are Car Kit's. Looking at the console log when I try this in my own car, I notice that I see mediaserverd[19] :  BTAudioXpcConnection.cpp within the console log. I am assuming therefore that the LEAudio perhaps points to the need to use the Low Energy side?

In short, 1) I need to list the paired devices, and 2) I need to get a notification when a given device connects.

Can anyone advise if this is possible, and if so, point me at some useful documentation, as the docs I have read so far do not seem to give me what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: bluetooth audio devices are managed through the av frameworks but they are only exposed as audio sources/destinations, there is no information about the Bluetooth side of things available.

Comment: Ah. That is a pain! I guess this is why I am struggling to find any information.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of bluetooth devices in range inside your app you can use the `CoreBluetooth` framework.

From here you can connect to the device and get its details.

If you design your app to show a list of all devices then allow the user to connect to one, saving this devices details will allow you to have a "My Devices" section in your app. Whenever they are in range simply connect to them.

I have made a wrapper round the CoreBluetooth framework to make it easier for people to use.

https://github.com/steprescott/SCPCoreBluetoothManager

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, it seems this will only work with Low Energy devices, and not with Classic Bluetooth, on which Car Kits etc work. Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: You would be right. It is only for BLE devices. I was not aware that your devices were not. Sorry

Comment: I am using this sample code but not show bluetooth Hands-Free Profile (HFP) on list. How can i show list of bluetooth headset devices ?

Comment: @YogendraGirase The comment above shows this only for BLE devices not Classic Bluetooth. Please see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35296855/1136076